# The text won't appear - pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I've asked this question before, but this time I did not make the same mistake of calling the text loop before making the screen blue.

```
def win1():
    print('Level 1 completed')
    global levelcount, var1, var2, clr, score, alive
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 100)
    textsurface = myfont.render('Level 1 completed', True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))
    for sprite in enemies:
        sprite.kill()
    pygame.time.wait(2800)
    levelcount = 2
    var1 = 700
    var2 = 900
    clr = (10, 85, 135)
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 100)
    textsurface = myfont.render('Level 2', True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))
    alive = True
    score = 0
```

That code is supposed to make it say "Level 1 completed", but it doesn't. Here is where I call it:

```
alive = True
while alive:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            alive = False
        elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
            new_opponent = random.choice([Enemy(), Bomb(), Blimp()])
            enemies.add(new_opponent)
            all_sprites.add(new_opponent)

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    enemies.update()

    screen.fill(clr)

    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies):
        player.kill()
        alive = False
        death()

    if levelcount == 1: #I call it here
        if score > 100:
            alive = False
            win1()
    if levelcount == 2: #this is for if you beat level 2
        if score > 100:
            alive = False
            win2()

    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I have a death part that makes it say "you died" and it works, but I used almost the same code from it for the win part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the display by [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) and to handle the events by [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) before  `pygame.time.wait(2800)`:

```py
def win1():
    # [...]

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.event.pump()
    pygame.time.wait(2800)

    # [...]
```

The changes made to the display *Ssurface* will only be visible if the display is updated using either either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip).
On some systems it is necessary to handle the event by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get)  in order to handle the redraw of the display. Handling the events ensures the program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.